# How to get mean value of each columns in a data frame

Tags: r

I want to get the mean value of each column in a data frame like below:

```
> x <- cbind(x1 = 3, x2 = c(4:1, 2:5))
> x
     x1 x2
[1,]  3  4
[2,]  3  3
[3,]  3  2
[4,]  3  1
[5,]  3  2
[6,]  3  3
[7,]  3  4
[8,]  3  5
> y <- colMeans(x)
> y
x1 x2 
 3  3
```

I can get the mean value from `y` but `y` is not a data frame. How can I get a return value of data frame? I need to use `cbind` on `y` to bind with other data frames.

Comment: data.frame(colMeans(x)) returns all data in one column. How can I make it in a row?

Comment: You can use `tidyverse` i.e `x %>% as.tibble %>% summarise_all(mean)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example x is a matrix. You have two option:

Option 1 - transform x into a data frame and then use sapply

```
x<-as.data.frame(cbind(x1 = 3, x2 = c(4:1, 2:5)))
x.df<-sapply(x,FUN=mean)

> x.df
x1 x2 
3  3
```

Option 2 - use apply and transform the result in a data frame

```
x <- cbind(x1 = 3, x2 = c(4:1, 2:5))
x.df<-as.data.frame(t(apply((x),MARGIN=2,FUN=mean)))

> x.df
x1 x2 
3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same then I found a solution like below

you have a numeric dataset

```
df <-  data.frame(a = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25),
                 b = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 c = c("name1","name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"))
```

you can either apply this for some specific columns

```
mysummary <- function(x){
  funs <- c(mean,sd,mad,IQR)
  lapply(funs,function(f) f(x,na.rm = T))
}

mysummary(df$a)
mysummary(df$b)
```

or for all the dataset

```
  mysummary2 <- function(x){
  if (is.numeric(x)){
    c(mean(x),median(x),sd(x), mad(x), IQR(x))
  }else{ print("pass")}
}

lapply(df,mysummary2)
```